# Jmeter SSH SFTP using ppk file

Tags: jmeter

I have to drop file in SFTP location and SFTP has ppk file instead password. I tried SSH SFTP with SSH key file locating to ppk file. But i am getting invalid primary key. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

SSH SFTP Sampler expects [Putty Private Key](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/), if you try to use OpenSSH id_rsa private key - you will get something like `Failed to connect to server: invalid privatekey: [B@somehexvalues]` error

- If your private key starts with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` - you won't be able to use it with SSH SFTP sampler
- If your private key starts with `PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa` - you will be able to use it (assuming the server has the corresponding public key)

If you need to convert OpenSSH or RSA private key to Putty PPK - use [PyttyGen](https://www.puttygen.com/) application.

More information: [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)